# Implement with cypress with page object model

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js, cypress, pageobjects

I'm trying to create cypress test project which support page object model.

I have created a new folder 'pageobject' at ../integration and there I have implemented LoginPageAdminPortal.js file as a page object class.

Code is like below,

```
export class LoginPageAdminPortal

{
    visitLoginPageAdminPortal()
    {
        cy.visit (cypress.env('ADMIN_PORTAL_LOGIN_URL'))

    }

    loginAdminPortal()
    {
        cy.get('input[name=usernameUserInput]').type(cypress.env('ADMIN_USER_NAME'))
        cy. get('input[name=password]').type(cypress.env('ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD'))
        cy.contains('Continue').click()
        return this
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a test script for user login and the test sript locate at integration folder.

```
import {LoginPageAdminPortal} from '/pageobject/'


describe('Admin portal login with username and password', () => {

    it ('Visit to the admil poratl login page', () => {
        const loginPage = new LoginPageAdminPortal()
        loginPage.visitLoginPageAdminPortal()

    })
})
```

But at the compilation time I'm getting error like,

```
Error: Cannot find module '../pageobject/' from '                    /home/achini/projects/cloudtest/cypress/cypress-iam-ui-test/iam-cypress-ui-test/cypress/integration'
```

Do I have to configure the pageobject module some other file. Any idea to solve this and successfully implement cypress with page object model.

folder structure

[image]

reference : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ifXs65O36k
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMiBundGmNA

Answer (score 2):

Imports are relative to the test which is in the `integration` folder, so you want

```
import { LoginPageAdminPortal } from './pageobject/LoginPageAdminPortal';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out these two repositories where I implemented an example of the PO pattern. In one repository, I did it with TypeScript, and in the other one, I did it with JavaScript.

https://github.com/antonyfuentes/cypress-typescript-page-objects
https://github.com/antonyfuentes/cypress-javascript-page-objects

Answer (score 0):

I think a good practice is to keep the integration folder only with your tests files. You can move the pageobject folder under support and use
`import LoginPageAdminPortal from '../../support/PageObjects/LoginPageAdminPortal'`in order to access the file.